# Understand the usage of `std::unordered_set`

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

struct MN
{
    MN(const int& _m, const int& _n)
        : m(_m), n(_n) {
            value = pow (m, n);
        }

    bool operator==(const MN& rhs) const {
        return m == rhs.m && n == rhs.n;
    }

    int value;      
    int m;
    int n;
};

struct MNHash
{
    size_t operator()(const MN& rhs) const {
        return hash<int>()(rhs.m) ^ hash<int>()(rhs.n);
    }
};

int main() {
    unordered_set<MN, MNHash> st;
    st.emplace(2, 3);
    st.emplace(3, 2);

    cout << st.size() << endl; // 2
    return 0;
}
```

Question 1> Is it true that the `unordered_set` uses `MN::operator==` to check whether the new item is duplicate or not?

Question 2> Is it true that the `unordered_set` uses 'MNHash' to compute the hash key of the new item?

Question 3> If the answers to both Q1 and Q2 are YES, then is it true that we will see a hash conflict in about code because both MN(2, 3) and MN(3, 2) have the same hash code?

Thank you

Comment: The question title has nothing to do with the question body.

Comment: @KerrekSB, made a change to the title and hopefully it works now.

Comment: Your hashing algorithm appears flawed to me: As long as `m` equals `n`, you'll get a hash collision since you return `0`. So `MN(1, 1)` should have the same hash as `MN(2, 2)`.

Comment: for first two questions, you can figure them out by adding log messages.

Comment: @Mario, this is the key reason why I posted this question. I saw this hash function is used in a book and have doubts about the correctness of it.

Comment: @Mario, what about this one `return (37*hash<int>()(rhs.m)) ^ hash<int>()(rhs.n);` instead?

Comment: @BryanChen: That's needlessly operational and indirect advice. You can answer the first two questions immediately by reading the class documentation.

Comment: @q0987: A hash function can't really be "incorrect"; it can however be "a very terrible choice". The hash data structure that uses it provides complexity guarantees conditional on statistical properties of the hash function.

Comment: @KerrekSB: it's a well known technique to verify that your understanding of the topic is correct. I don't feel there's a need to criticise it (= I don't agree with your phrasing).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Did you look at the revision history?

Comment: @KerrekSB: *now* I did. actually, that comment came *after* the editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. More or less. The default comparator for `std::unordered_set` will use [`std::equal_to`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to), which, unless specialized, will do `return lhs == rhs`.

   You can change this by either specializing `std::equal_to`, or by adding a third template argument to the `std::unordered_set`.
2. It will use the second template argument to compute the hash. In this case, you've passed `MNHash`, so it will use that to do the work.
3. Since the hash value of `MN(2,3)` and `MN(3,2)` are the same, they will be placed in the same bucket.